# How does the electron electric dipole moment (EDM) depend on supersymmetry?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, symmetry, electrons, dipole-moment

I have read a [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7534) that says that limit on the [EDM of the electron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_electric_dipole_moment) has now been measured to 12 times better accuracy. According to that paper, as I understood, there should be a difference in the measured value of the EDM depending on whether or not supersymmetry exists. What is the reason behind that? calculations are always my preference.

Comment: Check out http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0106089 for analysis of the electron EDM with SUSY.

Comment: The SUSY must be broken, else loop contributions to electric (and also magnetic) dipole moments sum to zero. Any 1PI $e_L e_r \gamma$ diagram contributes. With SUSY, we have extra selection/chargino or sneutrino/neautralino diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

[This note](http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~mreece/edm-notes.pdf) discusses the general form of contributions to the EDM, at tree, one and two-loop level.